# SQl Server - unable to refer composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL server,I have the table with composite primary keys as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Systems
(
Layer VARCHAR(25),
System_Name VARCHAR(25) ,
Sub_System_Name VARCHAR(25),
Q1_Scope VARCHAR(25),
Q2_Scope VARCHAR(25),
Q3_Scope VARCHAR(25),
Q4_Scope VARCHAR(25),
U20 VARCHAR(25),
Extracts_Requested VARCHAR(25),
Extracts_Received VARCHAR(25),
Control VARCHAR(25),
Extracts_Reviewed VARCHAR(25),
Control_Frequency VARCHAR(25),
System_Layer_Exists VARCHAR(25),
Notes VARCHAR(25),
Alias VARCHAR(25),
Extract_Requested_Date VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (Layer,System_Name,Sub_System_Name)
);
```

Now I want to refer the columns like Layer,System_Name,Sub_System_Name in to another table say:

```
CREATE TABLE Owns_System
(
Name VARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employees(Name),
 Layer VARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Systems(Layer),
System_Name VARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Systems(System_Name),
Sub_System_Name VARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Systems(Sub_System_Name),
Role VARCHAR(25)
);
```

It shows me the error that the table Systems

> "There are no primary/candidates keys in the table Systems".

Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to declare 3 separate foreign key constraints - you need to use a single composite foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE Owns_System
(
Name VARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employees(Name),
Layer VARCHAR(25),
System_Name VARCHAR(25),
Sub_System_Name VARCHAR(25),
Role VARCHAR(25),
constraint FK_Blah FOREIGN KEY (Layer,System_Name,Sub_System_Name)
     REFERENCES Systems(Layer,System_Name,Sub_System_Name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that
>   refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table

So Before referring a column (**PKey**) in one table (Say *TableA*) as Foreign key in another Table (**TableB**), You need to make sure that the Column **PKey** is the ***Primary Key / Unique Key*** in **TableA**.

The Table Design Might be something like this

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
PKey INT PRIMARY KEY,
FullName VARCHAR(50),
Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
FKey INT FOREIGN KEY References TableA(PKey),
Email VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY References TABLEA(Email)
)
```

Please Refer this [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) link for more in detail on **Foreign key**

Comment: thanks for your reply.I just want to refer multiple columns from the table A to table B. What can I do for it. Can you please provide me any samples

Comment: You Can Also set Unique Key's in one table as a foreign key in another. So, You may try to set the columns as a Unique Key if you want to refer multiple Column of the Same table as Foreign key in another